# exceptions.TypeError: cannot convert dictionary update sequence element #1 to a sequence?

Tags: python, web-crawler, scrapy

I use the opened project scrapy to crawl comment of video from Tencent, but error was arised. And I don't know how to figure it out.

```
2015-10-22 18:33:58 [scrapy] INFO: Scrapy 1.0.1 started (bot: qqtvurl)
2015-10-22 18:33:58 [scrapy] INFO: Optional features available: ssl, http11, boto
2015-10-22 18:33:58 [scrapy] INFO: Overridden settings: {'NEWSPIDER_MODULE': 'qqtvurl.spiders', 'SPIDER_MODULES': ['qqtvurl.spiders'], 'SCHEDULER': 'scrapy_redis.scheduler.Scheduler', 'BOT_NAME': 'qqtvurl'}
2015-10-22 18:33:58 [scrapy] INFO: Enabled extensions: CloseSpider, TelnetConsole, LogStats, CoreStats, SpiderState
2015-10-22 18:33:58 [qqtvspider] DEBUG: Reading URLs from redis list 'qqtvspider:star_urls'
Unhandled error in Deferred:
2015-10-22 18:33:58 [twisted] CRITICAL: Unhandled error in Deferred:


Traceback (most recent call last):
     File "D:\anzhuang\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\scrapy\cmdline.py", line 150, in _run_command
cmd.run(args, opts)
     File "D:\anzhuang\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\scrapy\commands\crawl.py", line 57, in run
self.crawler_process.crawl(spname, **opts.spargs)
     File "D:\anzhuang\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\scrapy\crawler.py", line 153, in crawl
d = crawler.crawl(*args, **kwargs)
     File "D:\anzhuang\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\twisted\internet\defer.py", line 1274, in unwindGenerator
return _inlineCallbacks(None, gen, Deferred())
--- <exception caught here> ---
    File "D:\anzhuang\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\twisted\internet\defer.py", line 1128, in _inlineCallbacks
result = g.send(result)
    File "D:\anzhuang\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\scrapy\crawler.py", line 71, in crawl
self.engine = self._create_engine()
   File "D:\anzhuang\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\scrapy\crawler.py", line 83, in _create_engine
return ExecutionEngine(self, lambda _: self.stop())
  File "D:\anzhuang\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\scrapy\core\engine.py", line 66, in __init__
self.downloader = downloader_cls(crawler)
  File "D:\anzhuang\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\scrapy\core\downloader\__init__.py", line 65, in __init__
self.handlers = DownloadHandlers(crawler)
  File "D:\anzhuang\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\scrapy\core\downloader\handlers\__init__.py", line 17, in __init__
handlers.update(crawler.settings.get('DOWNLOAD_HANDLERS', {}))
exceptions.TypeError: cannot convert dictionary update sequence element #1 to a sequence
2015-10-22 18:33:58 [twisted] CRITICAL:
```

And I add the following code in setting.py

```
DOWNLOAD_HANDLERS = {'S3', None,}
```

when I run the project, the above error was came out.
Thanks a lot!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because you are setting sequence elements into a dictionary.

You should have entered:

```
DOWNLOAD_HANDLERS = {'S3': None,}
```

or something like this.

You can read more about how to set values for `DOWNLOAD_HANDLERS` with **examples** here: http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/settings.html#download-handlers-base

Answer (score 1):

`{'S3', None,}` is a `set`, while the code expected `DOWNLOAD_HANDLERS` to be either a `dict` or a sequence of (key, value) tuples.

IOW replace `{'S3', None,}` with `{'S3': None}` and you shouldn't have this error.